# Nested property types in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to track nested property types on Vue?

I have this props setup:

```
// ...
props: {
    navigation: {
        type: [Array],
        default: () => {
            return [
                { type: String, icon: "home" },
                { type: String, icon: "star" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

right now i have validation only for first level which is array, but nothing happens inside of it. Can i check types inside one of type level? Thx for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "track nested property types"?  Do you mean, be able to assign types to them and have the compiler warn you when you are not complying with those types?

Comment: yeap, that's right

Comment: And are you referring to the return type from the `default` function?

Comment: yes, but what with the next level, i.e. of this icon strings?

Comment: What do you want `navigation` to be?  You have currently said it's type should be an Array but the default function you have defined returns an array of objects (with keys type and icon).  Note from the examples in the docs you posted it doesn't look like you type the return value from the default function.

Comment: Deep nested changes in properties and data don't rerender components as you might expect, as Vue can't properly track them. Sometimes you can achieve a rerender by temporarily nulling the variable and then assign its new value (nasty, I know and it only works for `data`). See also: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: @Lukas what about the answer below now?  It uses the validator function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to directly type the array of objects using the `type` attribute as [Vue prop validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation) says:

> The `type` can be one of the following native constructors:
>
> - String
> - Number
> - Boolean
> - Function
> - Object
> - Array
> - Symbol

Having said that it looks like you could define a validator function like:

```
props: {
    navigation: {
        validator: function (value) {
            if (!(value instanceof Array)) {
                return false;
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                if (typeof value.icon !== "string") {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        default: () => {
            return [
                {icon: "home" },
                {icon: "star" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great but i'm not using typescript, i just want to do this using only Vue it self, and delivered features - misunderstanding

Comment: Ah ok, you should remove the typescript tag from your question then.  What is your question?  Does Vue.js support a kind of type system of it's own using the `type:` attributes?  Can you point towards the docs that mention that?

Comment: hehehe, this validator is so hardcore, imagine that i have to define it for each data type and each component :) but thx for trying, cheers and good day, now i'm pretty sure that i will install typescript :D

Answer (score 2):

In addition to typescript and library like [vue-types](https://github.com/dwightjack/vue-types), I find `_.every` and `_.has` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#every) can make pretty readable solution for validating complicated prop.

```js
import every from 'lodash/every'
import has from 'lodash/has'

export default {
  name: 'navigation',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      validator: items =>
        every(items, (item) =>
          has(item, 'home') &&
          has(item, 'star')
        )
    }
  }
}
```

You can even write `has(item, 'home.adress.zip')` for deep nest object!

Answer (score 2):

[vue-types](https://github.com/dwightjack/vue-types) makes this easy to do. In the following example, notice the Array of strings:

```
    props: {

        picNum: VueTypes.number.def( 3 ),
        pics: VueTypes.arrayOf( String ).isRequired, // RIGHT HERE!
        step: VueTypes.number.def( 1 ),
        className: VueTypes.string.def( '' ),

    },
```

Plus vue-types has more helpers for defining the shape of objects, etc. Super nice to use with Vue props!